# when i am try to get text of a binding element, it gives the total text of the div element

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, protractor, end-to-end

```
**HTML code :**

<div align="left">
     {{input.visaValidFrom}} // visa valid from value is 2015-01-03
     - 
     {{input.visaValidTo}}   // visa valid to value is 2015-12-01
</div>
```

**Protractor code:**

```
expect(element(by.exactBinding('input.visaValidFrom')).getText()).toBe('2015-01-03');
```

**protractor error:**

```
Expected '2015-01-03 - 2015-12-01' to be ' 2015-01-03'.
```

Any one please help me , how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`element()` call here refers to an [`ElementFinder`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementFinder) which represents a single element. In other words, you are getting an element containing the binding (`div`), not the value of the binding itself.

You should assert the complete element text in this case:

```
expect(element(by.exactBinding('input.visaValidFrom')).getText()).toBe('2015-01-03 - 2015-12-01');
```

Or, you can manually [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the text by `-`:

```
element(by.exactBinding('input.visaValidFrom')).getText().then(function (value) {
    expect(value.split(' - ')[0]).toEqual('2015-01-03');
});
```

Comment: @rajanasekhar sorry, I'm trying to say this works as it supposed to work - returning you an element containing the binding, not the binding value itself.

Comment: Once again Thanks @alecxe.